# Intellij method type migration - change calls on returned object

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I am making a refactor on a method `getSomething()` that is executed from large number of places. The method returns Type1 which has members that will be accessed by callers of `getSomething()`

```java
public Type1 getSomething() { 
   return new Type1();
}
```

Type1 is defined as:

```java
public class Type1 {

   private String typeValue = "abc";

   public String getTypeValue() {
       return typeValue;
   }
}
```

And finally some code that gets the type value:

```java
public void run() {
   Type1 t = getSomething();
   String v = t.getTypeValue();
}
```

I want to perform type migration on `getSomething()` to return let's say an Optional with Type1:

```java
public Optional<Type1> getSomething() {}
```

But what I would also like is to create some sort of rules to automatically update all callers of `getSomething()` to get the value from Type1 wrapped in Optional i.e.:

replace `OldType.getTypeValue()` with `NewType.get().getTypeValue();`

So this would automatically do the following:

```java
public void run() {
   Optional<Type1> t = getSomething();
   String v = t.get().getTypeValue();
}
```

I cant' seem to find an easy way to do it in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

For the current moment there is no such tool in IDEA to provide the described behaviour. Please follow the feature request created for your issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211032